# Class unloading at JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classloader

I encountered the following case: 
I have a Singleton:

```
public class BookManager {
   private boplean initialized = false;
   private static BookManager instance;

   static {
      instance = new BookManager();
   }

   public void init() {
      //Performs some initialization code 
      initialized = true;
   }

   public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
       if (!initialized) {
          throw new Exception("Not initialized!");
       }
       //do some code to get the books list and return it 
   }
}
```

The singleton is initialized  and the init method is called during the application initialization, and works well. 
After some time (not sure why) - 
The use case where the exception is thrown is at at the following code:

```
BookManager.getInstance().getAllBooks();
```

I am sure that "init" method was called when the application started, 
so I suspect the BookManager class was unloaded. 
And when the above call was made, 
 the class was reloaded but no call to "init" method was made. 
Can someone explain in what cases a class loader is being collected by GC ? 
(why the class is begin unloaded?)

Comment: Do you redeploy the application? You you do coding in an IDE that could cause a redeployment?

Comment: No redeployment has occurred as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I could find no reference to unloading of classes in the [JBoss class loading documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7). However if you check out chapter [12.7. Unloading of Classes and Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7) of the JLS a class can only be unloaded once the class loader is no longer reachable. That means the application has to be undeployed first. This is something that's handled by the JVM so JBoss can't do much here.

Having that said, storing stuff in static variables is unsupported by Java EE.

What's the exception you get? `NullPointerException`?  What you can do is attache a debugger and check the object id of `BookManager.class` in the `#init` and `#getAllBooks` method. If it's the same (which I assume) no unloading happened.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. It's hard to reproduce this error. We have some singletons (not Singleton bean, but classic singletons). Maybe one of the approaches should be to move to Singleton bean? I am of course referring to @Singleton bean in my comment)